# Lorentz invariance and the orthogonality reation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, metric-tensor, coordinate-systems, inertial-frames

can somebody help me to find the solution?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Let $X$ be the set of components $x^a$ written as a column vector. Let $Y$ be the set of components $y^a$ written as a column vector. Let $X'$ and $Y'$ be defined similarly for the components $x'^a$ and $y'^a$. Let $g$ be the matrix whose components are $g_{ab}$. Then
$$
x^\mu y_\mu = X^T g Y
$$
where $T$ is the transpose and the product on the right is ordinary matrix multiplication (in this example a row vector multiplying a matrix multiplying a column vector).

Now let $\Lambda$ be the matrix whose components are $\Lambda^a_{\; b}$. Then
$$
X' = \Lambda X, \;\;\;\;\;\; Y' = \Lambda Y.
$$
Therefore
$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
x'^\mu y'_\mu &=& X'^T g Y' \\
&=& (\Lambda X)^T g \,(\Lambda Y) \\
&=& X^T \Lambda^T g \, \Lambda Y
\end{array}
$$
so if this is to be equal to $X^T g Y$ for any $X,Y$ then we must have
$$
 \Lambda^T g \Lambda = g
$$
QED.

The point of my adding this answer to others here is to show that many results in special relativity can be obtained by this sort of approach, where we adopt a matrix notation rather than an index notation, and as long as one uses them correctly the matrix methods are sometimes more transparent.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a contravariant 4-vector $y^\mu$ in an inertial frame frame of reference S, its components in another i.f.r. S'are $$x'^\mu=\Lambda^\mu_{\,\,\nu}\, x^\nu. \tag{1}$$

Lorentz invariance of $x_\mu y^\mu$ means that it has the same value in any i.f.r. related to another one by a Lorentz transformation, i.e. $$x'_\mu y'^\mu=x_\nu y^\nu. \tag{2}$$

Indices can be lowered using the metric $g_{\mu\nu}$, and this metric is the same in every inertial frame of reference, so $g'_{\mu\nu}=g_{\mu\nu}$. Using this fact on (2), we have

$$x'^\alpha g_{\alpha\mu}y'^\mu=x^\beta g_{\beta\nu}y^\nu.$$

If we use (1) in the left, we get $$\Lambda^\alpha_{\,\,\beta}\, x^\beta g_{\alpha\mu}\Lambda^\mu_{\,\,\nu}\,y^\nu=x^\beta g_{\beta\nu}y^\nu,$$

so $\Lambda^\alpha_{\,\,\beta}\, g_{\alpha\mu}\Lambda^\mu_{\,\,\nu}=g_{\beta\nu}$.